# Windows Phone app doesn't work on actual device (HTML reader)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created an application which reads the html of a certain page and collects some data out of it.
Once the application is running on my Windows Phone emulator it then works perfectly and I'm able to fetch the HTML data from the website. The problem occurs when the application is downloaded to a actual device (for example Nokia Lumia 525...). The html data is not shown on the device.

I'm not getting any errors, the app doesn't crash, I've uploaded the app to the windows phone store twice and everything went perfectly. I don't get any errors which I could refer to and therefore I'm unable to move forward with solving that problem. Maybe the website is blocking incoming request from the actual phone?. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using WebClient to retrieve the data? I hit some caching problems there. Try to make you requests unique to overcome this (add an additional `"?myguid=" + Guid.NewGuid()` or similar and try again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the date format. My emulator had this data format:

**MM/DD/YYYY**, whereas my actual device had this format: **DD/MM/YYYY**.